# Translate values to properties in DTL in Sesam

Tags: sesam

I have a list where a numerical value represent a property, i would like to be able to translate it inside the pipe.

Format matches this:

```
'15':'AA'
'10':'BB'
'20':'CC'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be solved by creating a mapping dataset that you look up using a DTL transform.

First we create the mapping dataset (in this case we just use an embedded dataset):

```
{
  "_id": "mapping",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "embedded",
    "entities": [{
      "_id": "15",
      "value": "AA"
    }, {
      "_id": "10",
      "value": "BB"
    }, {
      "_id": "20",
      "value": "CC"
    }]
  },
  "add_namespaces": false
}
```

We can then use this mapping:

```
{
  "_id": "mapper",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "embedded",
    "entities": [{
      "_id": "foo",
      "value": "15"
    }]
  },
  "transform": {
    "type": "dtl",
    "rules": {
      "default": [
        ["copy", "*"],
        ["add", "::mapped_value",
          ["coalesce",
            ["hops", {
              "datasets": ["mapping m"],
              "where": ["eq", "_S.value", "m._id"],
              "return": "m.value"
            }]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  "add_namespaces": false
}
```

The result is:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "foo",
    "mapped_value": "AA",
    "value": "15"
  }
]
```